# Why compile time error on instanceof operator but works fine on casting

Tags: java, instanceof

My question is, since  `new Test()` is neither sub class of `String` or it is String itself then why `instanceof` compilation fails ? Shouldn't it return **false**.

```
    public class Test{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
       //Compiles fails
       System.out.println(new Test() instanceof String);
      //compiles fine but run time class cast exception.   
        Test = (Test) new Object();;
        }
    }
```

Now i have edited my post, So this is what i really want to know why is this difference. Why compilation not failing on casting although it should

Comment: What is the message of compiler?

Comment: Compiler says- Incompatible conditional operand types TypeCasting and String

Comment: `Object t=new Test();
  if(t instanceof String ){
   
  }` if you say new Test() instanceof String, then you already know its not a string. instanceof works, if you are not sure, of which type the object is

Comment: But this is why instance of  operator comes into picture , I knew but logically it should show false as the result instead of compilation fails.

Comment: Its not duplicate please check again they are saying why there is no compilation error , I am seeking here explanation why there is error though it should be false

Comment: It is explained in the first duplicate proposal.

Comment: I have edited my question please check.

Answer (score 5):

`instanceof` cannot be applied if it is guaranteed at compile time to always return false.

The rule is that if casting the first operand to the type of the second operand would always throw `ClassCastException`, the compiler doesn't allow applying the `instanceof` operator on these operands.

An instance of your `Test` class can **never** be an instance of `java.lang.String`.

> **[15.20.2. Type Comparison Operator instanceof](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2)**
>
> If a cast (§15.16) of the RelationalExpression to the ReferenceType would be rejected as a compile-time error, then the instanceof relational expression likewise produces a compile-time error. **In such a situation, the result of the instanceof expression could never be true**.

Comment: I have edited my question please check .

Comment: @ShowStopper You have to think about`(String) new Test()`, not `(Test) new Object()`.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler knows that the type hierarchy of String is Object>String and the hierarchy of Test is Object>Test, therefore it can never be true.